# Add a median filter to adversarial examples

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, pytorch

How do I to add a median filter to the examples after adding the FGSM in this function.

> ```
> def fgsm_attack(image, epsilon, data_grad):
>     sign_data_grad = data_grad.sign()
>     perturbed_image = image + epsilon*sign_data_grad
>     perturbed_image = torch.clamp(perturbed_image, 0, 1)
>     return perturbed_image
> ```

I use this code.
https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/fgsm_tutorial.html

Comment: Here is a module that applies a Median filter given a kernel size (default 3)
https://gist.github.com/rwightman/f2d3849281624be7c0f11c85c87c1598